# Java mysql insert

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

i am a new user to programming, i have started learning Java and i have been writing a simple program to insert data entered in textfield of my UI to MYSQL,I am able to insert data to MYSQL db. but problem is i am not able to close the connection. When i write code to close connection in my program it is lot of errors.

MY code which is working for insert data without closing connection

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "mysql";
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        String sql= "insert into table1 (no,name,address,password) values ('"+numberr.getText()+"', '"+namee.getText()+"', '"+addresse.getText()+"', '"+passworde.getText()+"')";
        myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Insert complete");

    } catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

When i write close connection program my code looks like below and throws lot of errors:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "mysql";
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        String sql= "insert into table1 (no,name,address,password) values ('"+numberr.getText()+"', '"+namee.getText()+"', '"+addresse.getText()+"', '"+passworde.getText()+"')";
        myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Insert complete");

    } catch(SQLException se) {       
         se.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(myStmt!=null) {
                myStmt.close();
            }
        } catch(SQLException se) {
        }// do nothing
        try {
            if(myConn!=null) {
                myConn.close();
            }
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }//end finally
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");   
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors does it throw?

Comment: You should look into prepared statements for your SQL. That code will leave you open to SQL Injection.

Comment: To get proper help you need to write a proper question. Show the errors you have and put a minimal verifiable example of the code you are having problems with.

Comment: i am not able to run the file it says class xxx does not have a main method. But i have main method.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). This puts your connection code inside the resource braces and JVM will close the connection automatically for you when you are done or something goes wrong.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "mysql";

        try (Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {
            Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into table1 (no,name,address,password) values ('" + numberr.getText() + "', '"
                    + namee.getText() + "', '" + addresse.getText() + "', '" + passworde.getText() + "')";
            myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Insert complete");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so the above code is enough to close the db connection after the work is done.

Comment: Yes, when using try-with-resources then the connection will be automatically closed in both cases: normal execution and exception are both covered.